# How to test the stability of an OTA in this case?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, stability, ota

I am designing an OTA for a current buffer (images from [Analog Design Essentials](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b135984)):

[image]

The OTA is just used to provide a high gain, to regulate the voltage on RE. My question is, how to test the stability of an OTA used in this application?

[image]

The classic method we learned from classes is to configure the OTA as a source follower, and add a load capacitor representing the next stage at the output. In my case, the load is the gate of a transistor, which may be several hundreds of fF. This makes the gain bandwidth product (GBW) of the OTA very large (GBW\$=\frac{g_m}{2 \pi C_L} \$), and makes it hard to achieve a large phase margin. In my case, the phase margin is only 13 if I connect nothing as a load, but increases to 80 if I add a 1pF load.

Comment: That's not the symbol for an [operational transconductance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transconductance_amplifier).

Comment: Can you show a schematic of the OTA itself? The overall topology, number of stages, compensation, etc would be of significant interest for an answer. (FWIW, we *do* use that symbol for OTAs in integrated VLSI design classes, even if it doesn't match that used for *discrete* commercial OTAs and happens to elide the biasing details)

Comment: Hi @nanofarad, thanks for your comment. I rephrased my question. What confuses me the most is not the circuit but the methodology to test the stability.

Comment: That next stage is both capacitive and a part of the overall feedback loop so I'd expect it to be relevant for the overall stability - is there a reason you can't put the whole feedback loop (including the MOSFET and Re) into the simulation and put an `stbprobe` or `iprobe` or whatever for your stability analysis?

Comment: What software are you using to test stability, and also, one usually tests the stability of the whole feedback loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the whole (loop) in the analysis. Analyzing the OTA by itself doesn't inform much about the whole system.

While the transistor loads the OTA, the frequency response of the transistor (and the effects of its load) also affect the whole loop.

Present that the transistor and S load (RE) are all part of a larger OTA. It has a reference (the OTA's +), and a feedback node (S of FET to OTA's -). You can break the loop there and analyze the loop characteristics.

In the application, the FET's drain is the 'useful' output, but (if the transistor is reasonable), there is little interaction from the load on the D to the signals at the S (some D-S capacitance, r0 of the FET, and possibly some Miller effects of CDG if the load is high impedance). to be more precise, you should perform the analysis with the correct load on the D.

Comment: I increased the size of the transistor (the one loads the OTA) to 100u/2u to get a proper phase margin. Is it an odd design to use such a large transistor?

Comment: It depends on the technology and general levels of currents you are running. If you JUST want to improve PM, adding a C from G to GND might be just as good, and take less chip area.
Making the FET larger can be inefficient, as the output pole (1/gm*CLOAD) only moves as the sqrt(size)